# MailChimp HTML email template extend partial background on table rows

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, mailchimp

I am coding a custom email template HTML/CSS and I need to replicate the attached image. 
My question is about the blue background color element, which goes beyond two table rows, one would be the "Welcome to the family", and the other would contain the video. 
How can I implement that?

```html
<!-- BEGIN MODULE: BODY CONTENT // -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" valign="top">
   <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="background-color:#1D75B9; border:0;">
         <h2 style="margin:40px 20px; text-transform:capitalize; text-align:center;">Welcome to the family!</h2>
      </td>
   </tr>    
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">*|YOUTUBE:[$vid=fj77lSG6Bl8, $max_width=500, $ratings=N, $views=N, $border=N, $title=N, $trim_border=N]|*
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<!-- // END MODULE: BODY CONTENT -->
```

[image: email image to be coded]

Any example that makes the same thing would be helpful to me.

thank you

Comment: give your html code if possible able to help you better.

Comment: @aviboy2006 I just added the code on the initial post.

Comment: Using background image will solve it for you. Have the background image with blue and transparent, give it a height in VML and place the text and view above it (not in the image).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```html
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
        <div align="center">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" valign="top">
                   <tr>
                      <td valign="top">
                        <img src="WvLArjpg6991210.png">
                      </td>
                   </tr>    
                   <tr>
                      <td valign="top">
                        <img src="second.png" width="461">
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    </body>
```

[image]

[image]

You have cut images into pieces and use in `<tr><td><img src></td></tr>`

Comment: This is an actual MailChimp email template, with editable sections and real content, I cannot do it this way cause it won't be editable by the user within MailChimp.

Comment: link tracking will need to done seperatly for each. @FelipeToledo, have you tried background images and video on top?